# Not able to display single column in mysql select Query

Tags: mysql

From simple address table, if i select two columns, i am getting value of AddressLine1 but if i select single column, i am not getting value of AddressLine1.

Mysql query with two column: (Working fine) 
**select AddressLine1,AddressLine2 as v from address limit 10;**

Mysql query with single column (Not Working) 
**select AddressLine1 as v from address limit 10;**

[image]

For query output, please check attached image

Comment: It's possible who address line 1 is empty? Try remove limit and see what happens.

Comment: @RiccardoDegan, yes if i remove limit, i am able to see single column output addressline1 but why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is that you are missing a way for MySQL to order your data for output, ie. a Primary key, thus you might be getting a different order of results everytime you run your query.

If your table has this structure:
`ID (int), AddressLine1 (string), AddressLine(2)`
then you can run your query `SELECT AddressLine1 FROM address ORDER BY ID ASC limit 10;`

Comment: Yes if i put order by clause then i am able to get output